# Website looks smaller on Chrome and Firefox and bigger in Opera

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website with django and I'm using the new Opera browser (The one with the flow) as my main browser and when I opened my page in chrome and firefox I found out that the content is smaller on the other two browsers.

This is how my website looks in Opera: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSq9S.jpg

And this is how it looks on chrome and firefox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5Iaa.jpg

And this is my html/css file: https://del.dog/doqaraqice.htm

As you might see I tried a couple of thing while trying to fix this problem but none worked:
Tried width/height auto, max-width/height, adding the meta thing in my html, etc

EDIT: hmm, maybe is the way Opera renders websites.. Noticed while browsing Facebook that is bigger on Chrome and smaller on Opera.

Comment: Normally browsers have their own default style sheets. You normally write your own CSS classes to normalise things.

Comment: You should to use CSS-reset.

Comment: I used a CSS reset but after I did some changes to the search bar the same thing happened.

Comment: @JGFMK what do you mean? I have my own classes like .custom, .btn etc.

Comment: Exactly - you say h1,h2, p etc all have their own CSS settings, so the sizes are normalised. There's a great book from APress called CSS Design Patterns that goes into this in more detail. The version I have is a bit dated, but a lot still holds true.https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vEgwjUiNB_AC&pg=PA30&lpg=PA30&dq=css+design+patterns+normalised+style+sheets&source=bl&ots=E-H21d37Ga&sig=M--P1PGagbPZhQM38C8ANYH7-vg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi74fPjodrbAhVKtlkKHeorBtsQ6AEIcTAH#v=onepage&q=css%20design%20patterns%20normalised%20style%20sheets&f=false https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/